# Passing fields (instance variables) by arguments (parameters) inside an object - does it make sense?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, coding-style, code-quality

I believe this is language agnostic question - if it's not then please correct me.

Let's say I have a class (code snippet is a kind of 'pseudo code')

```
class Car:
  private steering_wheel
  private engine
  public Car(steering_wheel, engine):
    this.steering_wheel = steering_wheel
    this.engine = engine


  public void service():
     clean_steering_wheel()
     repair_engine()

  private void clean_steering_wheel():
    this.steering_wheel.do_stuff()

  private void repair_engine():
    this.engine.do_stuff()
```

which works well! But I could also change private methods a bit and let them use fields (i.e `steering_wheel` and `engine`) via arguments, not directly

```
   class Car:
  private steering_wheel
  private engine
  public Car(steering_wheel, engine):
    this.steering_wheel = steering_wheel
    this.engine = engine


  public void service():
     clean_steering_wheel(this.steering_wheel)
     repair_engine(this.engine)

  private void clean_steering_wheel(steering_wheel):
    steering_wheel.do_stuff()

  private void repair_engine(engine):
    engine.do_stuff()
```

Let's assume that all parameters(arguments) are passed by reference.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these solutions? Which is considered as better practice? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Questions like "[Which is better?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/317/what-is-the-best-vs-what-is-your-favorite-vs-what-x-to-use)" or "[What are the pros/cons of X?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons)" are generally too broad or opinion-based to have an answer. If there actually was a correct answer, programming languages would probably be forcing you to do the right thing instead of letting you choose. Do you have a specific design problem in a specific language that prompted this question?

Comment: @Ixrec I've been thinking about this problem when writing ruby code. Here is above pseudo code translated to ruby. https://gist.github.com/Bartuz/2eb9b8637e0997766e6c

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds very much a judgement call to your specific situation, but a couple considerations come to mind.  If the methods are private, and you don't have any reason *to* pass the parameter, I would probably avoid it if for no reason other than it being less complex.  You could also argue that there is a performance reason to avoid it, as there is no reason to pass additional parameters on the stack if they aren't needed.

One time I do find that I *do* pass a member as a parameter is with protected members.   Let's say a child class does something like add a second steering wheel that also needs to be cleaned.  In that case, it could (presumably) re-use the clean_steering_wheel method from the base class and pass a different steering wheel member.

Comment: Off topic questions happen a lot here. Trying to answer them only encourages the behavior. Recommended reading: Should one advise on off-topic questions?.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the field as an explicit parameter is better
if you're not invoking a method, but a function/static method:
The less data is available in a function,
the more explicit all dependencies are,
the easier it is to reason about that code.
So a function `clean_steering_wheel(steering_wheel)` will not surprise a user
by actually doing something with the engine.

However, a (private) method will already receive references
to the `engine` and `steering_wheel`
via the implicit `this` parameter.
If you have a `this` parameter in addition to an explicit `steering_wheel` parameter,
you are duplicating your data – which can lead to inconsistencies.
In particular, I'd be wondering why you didn't use the `steering_wheel` from `this`:
Are you operating on the `steering_wheel` of a different `Car`?
On a `steering_wheel` that does not belong to any `Car`?

In light of this, it would be less confusing to define `clean_steering_wheel` as

```
private void clean_steering_wheel():
  this.steering_wheel.do_stuff()
```

However, it would be even better to use a free function:

```
void function clean_steering_wheel(steering_wheel):
  steering_wheel.do_stuff()

void function repair_engine(engine):
  engine.do_stuff()

class Car:
  ...

  public void service():
    clean_steering_wheel(this.steering_wheel)
    repair_engine(this.engine)
```

, or static method:

```
class Car:
  ...

  public void service():
    clean_steering_wheel(this.steering_wheel)
    repair_engine(this.engine)

  private static void clean_steering_wheel(steering_wheel):
    steering_wheel.do_stuff()

  private static void repair_engine(engine):
    engine.do_stuff()
```

Which precise approach to use is quite language-specific, and also has impact on testability.
E.g. in C++, using free functions in an anonymous namespace affords the best encapsulation,
but actively hinders testability.
Private static member functions might be better, since they can be tested by a friend class.
In Java, you can't have free functions but *must* use “static methods”,
so the discussion is unnecessary.